# How to get the viber api key and auth token of viber to call viber rest Api,

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, viber

I am creating a rest Api in java using spring boot. In my application I want to integrate Viber Api in my applicationin which i want to send messages and make voice call using viber api. In viber api docsI am unable to get any information how to generate the api key and auth token or how to create the viber public account.

can you please suggest me the steps or any working example code how to achieve the above requirements.

Comment: link to example of viber-bot implementation from official viber github profile: https://github.com/Viber/viber-bot-java

Answer (score 0):

The [document](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#authentication-token) has clearly mentioned how to get authentication token. You have to store this token somewhere in properties file & use the same each time you make an api call.

If you get an error from viber, read the error code [documentation](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#error-codes) to know what wrong you have done. Go through there official documentation in detail.

If you don't know how to make an API call from Spring-boot, read more about [rest-template](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template).